# How to get attribute value and replace it in dynamically generated xml file?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a xml file . I have to search for an attribute and to replace its value with some value using c#
Further i dont know how many times does this attribute come and in how many elements as this xml is generated dynamically.
Any help over this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to load the document into a [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) instance, then find all occurrences of the respective attribute by using the [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) method of the `XmlDocument` instance with an XPath expression and modify them accordingly.

Here's an example:

Assume the following Xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
    <a/>
    <b myAttribute="someValue"/>
    <c myAttribute="someOtherValue"/>
    <d/>
    <e>
        <f myAttribute="yetAnotherValue" anotherAttribute="anIrrelevantValue"/>
    </e>
</test>
```

Save the Xml document as `test.xml`. In the same directory, compile the following program. It will change the values of all attributes that are called `myAttribute` (selected by the XPath expression `//@myAttribute`):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//@myAttribute")) {
            node.Value = "new value";
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

        doc.Save("test.xml");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

(For your convenience, it also outputs the Xml document before and after the modification.)

**With Namespaces**

Now, the example is extended with namespaces (the XLink one, as requested by the OP):

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <a/>
    <b xlink:myAttribute="someValue"/>
    <c myAttribute="someOtherValue"/>
    <d/>
    <e>
        <f xlink:myAttribute="yetAnotherValue" anotherAttribute="anIrrelevantValue"/>
    </e>
</test>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//@xlink:myAttribute", nsMgr)) {
            node.Value = "new value";
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);

        doc.Save("test.xml");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Remark 1: Note how only two occurrences of attributes called `myAttribute` are modified now, the third one (in the `<c>` element) does not belong to the namespace indicated in the XPath expression.

Remark 2: The namespace prefix used in the Xml file and the C# code happens to be the same (`xlink`), but this is not required. You could, for example, use `xl` in the C# code instead and obtain the same result (only showing the changed lines):

```
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//@xl:myAttribute", nsMgr)) {
```

Comment: Hey Mapper thanks for this....
I forgot to mention that attribute is of type xlink:href="some dynamic content"
Can you modify the code accordingly because it is giving error regarding prefix...

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding another example. I have left the original namespace-less example intact, though, as it is sufficiently different (simpler) than the one with namespaces and as such might help future readers who are not using namespaces.